# Regular + normal topological space implies completly regular space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ a regular and normal topological space. Prove $(X,T)$ is completly regular.

*Definitions:*

- $(X,T)$ is a regular topological space if $\forall C$ closed in $(X,T)$ and$\forall x\in X\setminus C \ \exists U, V\in T$ such that $C\subset U, x\subset V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.
- $(X,T)$ is a normal topological space if $\forall C_1, C_2$ disjoint closed in $(X,T)$ $\exists U_1, U_2\in T$ such that $C\subset U_1, C_2\subset U_2$ and $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$.
- $(X,T)$ is a completly regular topological space if $\forall C$ closed in $(X,T)$ and $\forall x\in X\setminus C \ \exists f:(X,T)\longrightarrow ([0,1],T_u|_{[0,1]})$ continuous map such that $f(x)=0, \ f(C)=1$.

**My attempt**

Let $C$ closed in $(X,T)$ and $x\in X\setminus C$. I want to find some $F$ closed in $(X,T)$ such that $x\in F\subset X\setminus C$ and apply Urysohn's Lemma to the closets $C$ and $F$. I am trying to find this $F$ with the regularity condition, but I am having some troubles, can anybody guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I alraedy know the answer. If $(X,T)$ is regular, $\forall x \in X, \ x$ has a basis of closed neighbourhoods in $(X,T)$. So as $x\in X\setminus C\in T$, we can find some closed neighbourhood such that $x\in F\subset X\setminus C$, and then apply Urysohn's Lemma to $F$ and $C$.